# Is there a way to 'tee' input to a program or script?

Tags: command-line, stdin

I'm trying to find a way to use an input file for a program in such a way that I can also use stdin.

For example, say I have a SQL script that creates a table.  I invoke it like this:

```
mysql -p database < script.sql
```

This is great, but it exits out of mysql when the script is finished.  Instead, I want to run other queries manually without being logged out of mysql.

I know `tee` can fork output to the terminal (stdout) and to a file, is there a reverse function that can be used for input, or at least a method that can be applied to most Linux/Unix commands?

Comment: Not exactly similar. But you may take a look into this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463106/how-to-keep-a-mysql-connection-open-in-bash

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
cat script.sql - | mysql -p database
```

Comment: Do you lose the prompt with this? When I do the same with *`sh`* it reads and executes commands but I get no shell prompt. Same goes for redirecting <$(tty).

Comment: @mikeserv, yes, the prompts are only issued when stdin is a terminal. Here, it's a pipe.

Comment: does the same apply to mysql? I had it working by shuffling in/out around with exec at the tailend of a heredoc (which is a trick i only picked up in the first place due to some years old bash mailing list email of yours, i think), but im trying to figure on how i could do any execing if sql was the shell... Possibly that option's right out.

Comment: @mikeserv, there's no redirection trick that will work here. Either mysql stdin is a terminal or it's not. It has to be a terminal to get a prompt, so you'd have to have the terminal feed the content of the sql file to mysql. That could be done with the TIOCSTI ioctl under some circumstances, but it would be a lot saner to coerce mysql into reading the file before issuing a prompt.

Comment: My suspicions confirmed then. Thanks for the feedback, @Stephane.

Comment: @mikeserv, by the way, your answer (now deleted) as it is would work with `zsh`, which with the `mult_ios` option implements a `cat` internally when a fd is redirected for input several times (but that's still a pipe, not a terminal).

Comment: Well, thats why i deleted it. It was a compromise at best. I prefer lowest common denominator or nothing at all. Yours was that and simpler to understand so mine was superfluous. Thanks for the mention though.

Answer (score 5):

I like @Stephane's answer for the general case, but here's something more appropriate for your specific example.

Start up MySQL interactive mode and use the `source` command to run SQL scripts.

```
$ mysql -p  
Enter password:  
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.  
Your MySQL connection id is 947  
Server version: 5.1.73-1 (Debian)  

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.  

mysql> source asdf.sql  
+------+  
| test |  
+------+  
| test |  
+------+  
1 row in set (0.00 sec)  

mysql> select 'cool';  
+------+  
| cool |  
+------+  
| cool |  
+------+  
1 row in set (0.00 sec)  

mysql>
```